# How to connect one of primary domain access with another subdomain

Tags: dns

I have domain coupen.tk and a sub domain coupons.yadvi.com.I have web data in coupons.yadvi.com. i want so DNS configuration that if any one visit Coupen.tk they can see all information of coupon.yadvi.com but the link should be shown of coupen.tk not of coupons.yadvi.com

i have added the ip address of yadvi.com in coupoen.tk DNS A Record ,Ip Address of yadvi.com which will be same for coupons.yadvi.com.

Answer (score 0):

coupen.tk needs to point to the same A record IP address as coupons.yadvi.com, so they both resolve to the same server. That server then needs to be configured to serve the same site for requests to both domains.

The usual way to do that would be to make coupen.tk the "master" A record and configure coupons.yadvi.com as `CNAME coupen.tk`, so it points to that master record. The web server still needs to be configured to serve the same site for either domain.

Failing that, you'll need to set up a reverse proxy server which literally forwards requests for one domain to the other.

Comment: can you explain me more
as i have added a recored with ip address of Coupons.yadvi.com in dns of coupen.tk and also added cname record for 

please refer image any addition required
http://coupons.yadvi.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/coupons.yadvi_.png
http://coupons.yadvi.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/coupen.tk_.png

Comment: So, do those domains resolve to your server now? Does the server handle it?

Comment: coupen.tk had adopted the server of coupons.yadvi.com but not connected to its data. i can see only a default page .if you want you can check the web address coupen.tk .yet coupons.yadvi.com is a distinct web address not connected to coupen.tk